# transitionFromViewでスライド遷移をしたい

Tags: ios, objective-c

「UIView#transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:」のメソッドでは限られたアニメーションしかないが、push遷移のような左右にスライドするアニメーションを設けたいです。

Answer (score 1):

Core Animationフレームワーク（Quartz Core Framework）の`CATransition`クラスを利用してください。

[CATransition Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransition_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004507)

[Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514)

[Transition Animations Support Changes to Layer Visibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH8-SW7)

Comment: 使い方のヒントを教えていただけたら嬉しいです。（主にスライドアニメーションにする部分）

Comment: プログラミングガイドのリンクも貼っておいたんですけど、なにか？

Answer (score 1):

pushっぽいアニメーションはこんなかんじですよ。

```
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                     forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.delegate = self;
    transition.duration = .4f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = (isRight)? kCATransitionFromLeft : kCATransitionFromRight;
    [targetView.layer addAnimation:transition
                                     forKey:nil];

    [CATransaction commit];
```